# string index out of range: 7 error

Tags: java

Hello I'm writing a code that asks the user for a tweet then tells the user if the tweet is the correct length and how many #'s @'s and links that are in it but everytime I run this I get the error string index out or range: 7. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter a tweet: ");
        String tweet = scan.nextLine();

        int hashtags = 0;
        int attributions = 0;
        int links = 0;


        if (tweet.length() > 140) {
          int excess = tweet.length()-140;
          System.out.println ("Excess Characters: " + excess);
        } else {
          System.out.println ("Length Correct.");
          while (tweet.length() <= 140) {
            if (tweet.charAt(0) == '#'){
              hashtags ++;
            }
            if (tweet.charAt(0) == '@'){
              attributions ++;
            }
            if (tweet.substring(0,8) == "http://") {
              links ++;
            }
            tweet = tweet.substring(1);
            }
          System.out.println ("Number of Hashtags: " + hashtags);
          System.out.println ("Number of Attributions: " + attributions);
          System.out.println ("Number of Links: " + links);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger, examined variables, etc?  Take a look at you logic for parsing "http://"

Comment: One side note, in Java you check string equality with `String.equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems, at least. The first is that you should not use `substring` on a string that's too short. It's far better to use [`String.startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)):

```
if (tweet.startsWith("http://")) ...
```

so that you don't have to even *worry* about the length of the string, or getting your character count wrong, or having it fail because you used `==` rather than [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) :-)

---

Secondly, regarding the following code:

```
while (tweet.length() <= 140) {
    :
    tweet = tweet.substring(1);
}
```

That's going to *keep* going once your string is empty, simply because zero (and every negative number for that matter) is less than 140.

And, of course, doing something like `tweet.charAt(0)` on an empty string is going to give you a bit of a problem, similar to your use of `substring`. You need to re-examine your terminating condition for the loop, making it something like:

```
while (tweet.length() > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're trying to get an 8-length substring of the tweet string without knowing how long the tweet is. What if the tweet is only 6 characters? If it is, you get an index out of bounds exception because you're looking two indices past where the array ends.

You should add a conditional guard:

```
if (tweet.length() >= 8 && tweet.substring(0,8).equals("http://")) {
    links++;
}
```

The && operator means that tweet.substring() will never be checked if the length of the string is less than 8, so you avoid stepping out of bounds.

The second problem is that, even once you add that condtional guard, what you're doing doesn't make any sense. The length of the string returned by substring(beginIndex, endIndex) is equal to endIndex - beginIndex, or 8 in this case. The string "http://" is only seven letters, so it's logically impossible for an 8-character string to ever equal it. Use the startsWith() function instead of substring from the 0 position:

The line from before should look like so:

```
if (tweet.startsWith("http://")) {
    links++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely use a for loop instead:

```
String string= "hello";
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i)
{
    if (string.charAt( i ) == '#')
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

That will insure that you traverse the entire string correctly.

Secondly, you need to make sure that the substring(0, 8) is inbounds before you assume. That is probably what's causing your error in some test cases.

Comment: How so? I gave a constructive example of an easier way to traverse the tweet/string as well as pointed out what is most likely giving the out of bounds error.